# Display button in HTML at top of page when button requires php output from lower in the code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Apologies for the horrific title - I had no idea how to summarise my needs (I have basic understanding of coding only through self-teaching).

I'm working on a HTML page that is built inside a php file, the page is part of a Wordpress site. The reason it's based on php is because it pulls information from a users profile and displays it.

I have a button that downloads a generated pdf of the content using Dompdf. The code for button is below:

```
<div class="download_pdf">
<form action="<?php echo get_bloginfo(template_directory) . '/pdf.php'; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="html" value="<?php echo base64_encode($output); ?>" />
    <input class="download-pdf" type="submit" value= "Download PDF" />
</form>
</div>
```

It takes the output from the code above it to generate the pdf, however currently this means I need to display the button at the end of the page, so that the output exists above the button code.

Ideally I want the button to be displayed at the top of the page where it is more easily viewable by the user however I'm not sure how as the page crashes due to no output existing at the point of creation (at least I believe that's the problem).

Comment: Where does `$output` actually come from? Can you provide an example of how it's defined?

Comment: You should also consider using `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_bloginfo()`

Comment: You could consider using some CSS so you can output the button after the code is run and position it (fixed or absolutely) at the top of the page.